# Glossary print a specific definition

Tags: glossaries

How does one print a specific glossary entry, i.e. the definition, such that:

```
\newglossaryentry{hardware}
{
    name        = {Hardware},
    description = {...}
}
```

and, for example:

```
\glossaryDescription{hardware}
```

outputs

```
...
```

I can't seem to find a method to do this, the glossary specification only talks about referencing particular entries so that they become visible wherever you `\printglossary`, but I want to be able to use the definitions throughout my document as well.

Any advice/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the following macro available in the glossaries package?

```
\glsdesc[<options>]{<label>}[<insert>]
\Glsdesc[<options>]{<label>}[<insert>]
\GLSdesc[<options>]{<label>}[<insert>]
```

and the (*) versions exist as well.

From the documentation `\glsdesc`

> is similar to \glstext except that it always uses the value of the
>   description key